# AFNetworking Overload a Post Parameter

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, networking, afnetworking

I am migrating from ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking and have run into an issue.

I am trying to hit an API with a request that overloads the post parameter.  I was previously using ASIFormDataRequest for this and used this code to update 3 ids at the same time.

```
// ASIHTTPRequestCode
[request addPostValue:@"value1" forKey:@"id"];
[request addPostValue:@"value2" forKey:@"id"];
[request addPostValue:@"value3" forKey:@"id"];
```

Since AFNetworking uses an NSDictionary to store key value pairs, it doesn't seem straight forward how to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't immediately see a direct way to do this with AFNetworking, but it is possible to do.

If you look at the code for `AFHTTPClient requestWithMethod`, you'll see this line, which is the one that sets up the request body to contain the parameters:

```
 [request setHTTPBody:[AFQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding(parameters, self.stringEncoding) dataUsingEncoding:self.stringEncoding]];
```

Basically you could pass an empty dictionary to `requestWithMethod` for the parameters, then it returns, call `request setHTTPBody` yourself, making up the query string yourself in a similar way to the way `AFQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding` does it.

Comment: I was hoping to figure this out without going this route, but it appears to be the only way right now.

Comment: I'm sure the AFNetworking guys would love to receive a patch that adds a better way to do this :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can build the request this way:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain.com/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSDictionary *postValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",@"value1",@"value2",@"value3"] forKey:@"id"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/path/to/your/page.php" postValues];
```

Comment: Ah sorry, now I understand your problem.  I updated my code above with something else you might try.  Not sure if it will work, I think it will depend on how your server interprets the request.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue but solved it by updating the url. I added the parameters i need to send with the url and set the "parameters to nil"

so the url became something like

```
server\url.htm?data=param1&data=param2&data=param3
```

and sent nil as paramDictionary

```
[request setHTTPBody:[AFQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding(nil, self.stringEncoding) dataUsingEncoding:self.stringEncoding]];
```

Comment: we are doing Post only for all the request and it is working beautifully for me

Comment: What API are you hitting with this?  I don't believe it should be working.

Comment: WAS server... implemented using j2ee .... it is working perfectly fine.... i am able to receive the parameters and process the request

Comment: My guess is that you are pulling those parameters on the server as GET parameters even though you are sending a POST request.

Comment: what would be the point of doing that.... the backend is set in a way that of we send as GET, the behaviour fails at times and some issues occur...... it is working with POST only and backend is also working with POST only